# How to avoid "presentism" or "historical transposition" in writing papers?

Tags: research-process, writing-style, reference-request

I am seeking any published writing style guidance or good/best practices to help with writing a paper so as to avoid introducing the taint of what is called *"[presentism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presentism)"* also known as *"historical transposition"*.

I found [this webpage at RationalWiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Presentism) which gives a good solid definition of the topic, and points out that there are two very different uses of the word, one for historical matters and one for philosophical matters.

> *Please note: I am **NOT** interested in the philosophical context of this word (i.e. the contrast to eternalism).*

In essence the following excerpt seems most relevant to the topic I am asking about...

> **presentism is a style of writing or argument that can be fallacious**, depending on the circumstances. [...] Another common form of presentism is allowing present-day moral judgments to creep into characterizations of the historical figures. [...] In good scholarly historical work, like in law, it's imperative to separate the consequences of the action from the intent.

Hopefully such guidelines can help writers in two ways:

1. Show the researcher/writer *how to identify* subtle forms of presentism and related pitfalls that may creep into the text.
2. Show how to write a paper in a manner that *helps the reader* to avoid their own tendencies towards a presentist view.

Presentism is the concept that we as humans have a tendency to interpret history using modern world views by either condemning the past based on modern day societal norms (ex: ridiculing American 19th century indecency laws such as bathing suit requirements) or else discounting the significance of past societal norms that once were but are no longer acceptable (ex: asserting that sending people to debtor's prison can not happen in modern America). There are other more subtle forms however, such as the perception of implicit superiority of the present over the past in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific concept in anthropology and history, rather than about academia.

Comment: Respectfully @jakebeal, I am asking about how this concept is applied in academic research for *any topic* (as a writing technique). As I mentioned above this concept is **not** exclusive to just Anthropology or History. It obviously could be applied to *any subject matter with a historical context* such as **Medicine**, **Philosophy**, and even **Pedagogy** and **Andragogy**.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to ask this on [history.se]? I see you're a member there. It might be worth flagging for migration there: I'm not sure if this is the sort of question they answer - it would be worth checking out their help page, and looking for similar reference requests on their site, to see if they accept that sort of question.

Comment: Note that I tagged this with **writing-style** which is my primary interest on the topic. I believe my question fits that tag's description: "*Questions about the tones, turns of phrase **and other writing patterns** that are appropriate for writing in an academic context.*" (emphasis added).

Comment: @O.M.Y. I'm afraid that I'm rather confused now: are you trying to figure out how to write about "historical transposition" or how to avoid "historical transposition" in your own work?  And are you sure you've even got the words right, since Google doesn't seem to turn up anything coherent?

Comment: @jakebeal - The latter: how to avoid H.T. in my own work. Looking for any sort of academic essays or guidelines on that topic. I know I can work some of it out for myself but I was advised to do some research on how others have handled the matter. As for Google's not being helpful, **that** is why I came here. :-) Perhaps this is known by some other term?

Comment: So far the only thing I can find that uses this term as defined is [this paper](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/27810/1/David%20Clark%20thesis.pdf) on page 10. It is not much help towards my question but it does (loosely) support the actual phrase being used for this concept.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "cultural transposition"?

Comment: @scaaahu - I don't think the two terms are synonymous but I do think they are quasi-related. The one refers to inevitable changes over time within a given society and the other seems to refer to changes/differences between geographies/cultures and the potential for cross-cultural contamination. Of course these two items can and often are related (*culture changes over time*) so I think there is some benefit to exploring this concept as well. Thank you.

Comment: The reason I ask the question in my previous comment is because your two examples in the question. Indecency laws such as bathing suit requirements is still applicable in some culture. Debtor's prisons still exist in some countries. And they might have little to do with history.

Comment: What you say about such cultural norms still being present in some areas of the world is true, but you will also note I mentioned "**19th century** indecency laws" so there was definitely a historical context to the example I used. There also seems to be a sort of [**return of the debtors prison in the US**](http://harvardcrcl.org/debtors-prisons-in-the-21st-century/). On an OT side note it appears I was being Anglo-centric in my examples and that is a form of viewpoint bias I will need to watch out for apparently.

Comment: Is this article [A Typology of Derivatives: Translation, Transposition, Adaptation](http://www.bokorlang.com/journal/60adaptation.htm) any use to you?

Comment: I have reworded the question hopefully to make it more on topic.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is something you should avoid.

Comment: I don't know any formal guidelines about that but I was always told by senior academics to be aware that technology, general knowledge and methods might have greatly improved since the time a given paper was written. In consequences, the appropriate thing to do was to **be descriptive about the shortcomings** and avoid harsh judgment (reserve it for the plentiful bad contemporary academic output).

Comment: In what areas are you primarily interested? In my areas of interest (math, computer science) it is very rare that you reference papers that are more than, say, 20 years old, and most of those much older that are still relevant aren't *that* far off in technique/methods that this is a serious problem. True, it is easy to be harsh on the pioneers, as the slick techniques nowadays in vogue are refinements of theirs, but even so I don't see this as very relevant.

Comment: @vonbrand I am working on a Philosophy related project. It is a personal project that I hope might lead to a minor publication someday.

Comment: I would be interested to see an example of presentism in a literature review/paper. My 2c. In disciplines that view their work as progressing from earlier work, older work may _seem_ simple. One can (and ought), however, to avoid condescending commentary by positioning it as a building block that contributed to the current state of knowledge. Philosophers, though, often structure essays as, "Socrates said X but I think Y". Here the problem is to check one's premises for presentism. I'm not certain that such a process would differ from that of constructing a strong argument in the first place.

Comment: A bit late reply but I tend to agree with @jakebeal that this is off topic. Perhaps, you can rephrase and ask in Philosophy or Writers' SE. Why? Because it is not just application of a concpet - in fact, the application itself could be criticized using the concept in question. In short, there is no single answer for this question and I am coming from a historicity perspective. There are various school of thoughts  (within different disciplines) treating these concepts differently. If someone can propose such general guideline, it'd be a philosophical breakthrough :-)

Comment: @Parrhesiastes Can you please flag the question for closing, giving this reason? (I would do so myself, but cannot until my old closure flag clears)

Answer (score 1):

Follow links on historiography - there are lots out there.  Historiography is both an academic discipline and a name for a text that outlines and contextualises a question with particular focus on how and why and when and where it was approached by whom.

Reading in this area will help you to understand why 'presentism' is an issue in academic writing and how to spot it in your own thinking and writing.

The other advice I can give is to say that if you pay attention to any good academic writing you will see that there are clear indications of what is intended as empirical and what is inferred.

Proper use of references and citations will help you to avoid accusations of being wholly subjective.  If you want to get across a value statement why not find a quote from someone contemporary to the event whose opinion mirrors your own.  Do not forget to include and consider opinions that contradict your own as well.  You can weigh the merits of an argument voiced by others.  Of course, ultimately, your findings will be influenced by your own background and social context.  Try to be clear and honest with yourself and your audience about when and how this is happening.

Comment: bikedragon: First, I appreciate the general academic writing advice you offer, it mirrors advice from colleagues. Second, regrettably I cannot accept your Answer for this Question. The discipline of historiography is too expansive and encompasses far more material than just academic writing styles. While I am certain I (and future readers of this Question) would eventually learn from reviewing the material of the field, suggesting the whole of historiography is akin to handing a doctoral thesis for intercultural communication theory to someone wanting to know how to write a persuasive speech.

Comment: All that said, the *bounty* is yours since you were the only one who even tried to answer the question before or after the bounty was posted.